# Testing SilverStripe email contact forms from local server

Tags: php, forms, email, mamp, silverstripe

I am building a contact form which sends an email upon submission using a combination of approaches provided in SilverStripe documentation ([Introduction to frontend forms](https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/introduction-to-frontend-forms/), and [Simple contact form](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/forms/how_tos/simple_contact_form)).

The code (included below) seems to be working fine, however I am wondering if it is possible to send test emails from a local server (in my case, MAMP) to properly test the functionality.

Many thanks in advance

```
public function ContactForm() {
        $form = Form::create(
            $this,
            __FUNCTION__,
            FieldList::create(
                TextField::create('Name','')
                    ->setAttribute('placeholder','Name*')
                    ->addExtraClass('form-field'),
                EmailField::create('Email','')
                    ->setAttribute('placeholder','Email*')
                    ->addExtraClass('form-field'),
                TextareaField::create('Message','')
                    ->setAttribute('placeholder','Message*')
                    ->addExtraClass('form-field')
            ),
            FieldList::create(
                FormAction::create('submit', 'Send Message')
                    ->setUseButtonTag(true)
                    ->addExtraClass('text-button')
            ),
            RequiredFields::create('Name','Email','Message')            
        );

        $form->addExtraClass('contact-form');

        return $form;
    }


    public function submit($data, $form){
        $email = new Email();

        $email->setTo('email@email.com');
        $email->setFrom($data['Email']);
        $email->setSubject("Contact Message from {$data["Name"]}");

        $messageBody = "
            <p><strong>Name:</strong> {$data['Name']}</p>
            <p><strong>Message:</strong> {$data['Message']}</p>
        ";
        $email->setBody($messageBody);
        $email->send();

        $form->sessionMessage("Thanks for your message, I'll get back to you as soon as I can",'good');

        return $this->redirectBack();
    }
```

**Edit: 8/04/17**

As [per](http://www.blog.tripleroi.com/2012/05/solvedenabling-sendmail-on-localhost.html) have updated the sendmail fields in the php.ini files in MAMP (both in MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf and MAMP/conf/php5.6.10) to:

```
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
;sendmail_path =/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f  ryanachten@gmail.com
```

As [per](https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/advanced-environment-configuration) have updated the mysite/_config/config.yml to include:

```
Email:
  send_all_emails_to: 'ryanachten@gmail.com'
```

All to no avail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to making the `_ss_environment` changes suggested above, the true barrier for testing email delivery in my case was *allowing less secure apps* to communicate with the email account used for testing.

I was initially using Gmail for this, which doesn’t allow less secure apps to be enabled for accounts with 2-step authentication. I could have changed this security feature, but instead opted to use a secondary, Yahoo email address for these trials.

Note: this answer is only intended to be applicable to the *testing* nature of this question (making sure the email functionality is executing appropriately); further steps will be made later in development to qualify as a secure email app.

Hopes this helps others in a similar situation.

**Resources:**

- [Allowing less secure apps to access your account (Gmail)](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)
- [Ways to securely access Yahoo Mail (Yahoo)](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN27791.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes - any emails sent using the SilverStripe Email class can be redirected for testing purposes:

```
# File: conf/ConfigureFromEnv.php
if(defined('SS_SEND_ALL_EMAILS_TO')) {
    Config::inst()->update("Email","send_all_emails_to", SS_SEND_ALL_EMAILS_TO);
}
```

[Reference](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.5.3/conf/ConfigureFromEnv.php#L121-L126)

Then this is used to override email destinations here:

```
# File email/Email.php
public function send($messageID = null) {
    // ...
    if($sendAllTo = $this->config()->send_all_emails_to) {
        $subject .= " [addressed to $to";
        $to = $sendAllTo;
        // ...
```

[Reference](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.5.3/email/Email.php#L601-L603)

So to utilise this, define `SS_SEND_ALL_EMAILS_TO` in your environment configuration:

```
# File: _ss_environment.php
define('SS_SEND_ALL_EMAILS_TO', 'your@email.com');
```

Comment: Forgot about the email environment definition. Have made this addition, however, am still unable to send emails from the form to a Gmail account.

Echoing out attributes of the email object show expected values have been assigned, however nothing seems to happen when `.send()` is executed. Strangely, some previous tests have sent to the ‘spam’ folder, however I have been unable to replicate these results.

Looking at outside of the Silverstripe context, does `SMTP` and `sendmail_path =` need to be configured in the MAMP `php.ini` file for this to work? (working in OS X)

Comment: That's a different question, but there is plenty of other examples of the same question asked on Stackoverflow already

Comment: you’re totally right; the scope of this question should have been clarified. Yes, existing posts on SO have been invaluable. I wasn’t sure whether the cause of this issue lied in my SilverStripe or MAMP setup (hence posting an additional question). I have somewhat solved this problem for testing purposes - will post it below.